# Pass dropdownlist value (bound from datatable) to another aspx page through session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to pass a DropdownList variable to another page through session state.

I have two DropDownLists. One is populated from a List and the other is bound to a Datatable. I am able to retrieve the variable from the first DropDownList to the second aspx code-behind file using this line of code ...

```
autogroup = Session["autogroup"].ToString();
```

However, when I attempt retrieve the value from the second DropDownList, the value is always NULL. Why would I not be able to pass the variable from the DropDownList that is populated from a DataTable?

This is the line I am using on the second code behind file to retrieve the value from the second DropDownList on the first page...

```
autosize = Session["autosize"].ToString();
```

And here is the code-behind for the fist page (sanitized for posting, removed GetQuery method and other irrelevant stuff)....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class WebForm12 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string autosize;
        public string autogroup;
        private string query;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                FillDropDown();
            }
        }

        protected void toolgroupddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
            sizeDropDown.DataSource = this.GetSizeRecords();
            sizeDropDown.DataTextField = "att1";
            sizeDropDown.DataValueField = "att1";         
            sizeDropDown.DataBind();

            Session["autogroup"] = Request.Form[autoGroupDropDown.UniqueID];  
        }

        protected void sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            Session["autosize"] = Request.Form[sizeDropDown.UniqueID];
        }

        private void FillDropDown()
        {
            List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
            items.Add(new ListItem("Cars", "CAR"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Trucks", "TRU"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("SUVS", "SUV"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Boats", "BOA"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Motorcycles", "MOT"));
            autoGroupDropDown.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
        }

        private DataTable GetSizeRecords()
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string query = GetQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

What am i missing? Is it because the second DropDownList is being populated from a DataTable, or does it have something to do with post back?  I am at a loss here.

Comment: Are you sure that when you set value to session, it isn't null?

Comment: It is NULL, yes.

Comment: However the second DropDownList is populated, and I can retrieve the values from its own code behind using SelectedItem.Text and SelectedValue. Just not using Session state from second page

Comment: Why then aren't you just doing `Session["autosize"] = sizeDropDown.SelectedValue;`?

Comment: can't understand your question and code

Comment: @DanDumitru I have tried that. As I said in the comment above yours, I can pull those values using SelectedItem.Text and SelectedValue on the same page, but cannot with session state on second page

Comment: @Asif.Ali Why would I not be able to pass the variable from the DropDownList that is populated from a DataTable?

Comment: As you are passing a `List` to first ddl and second is not a `List`.